# Why won't my trade port accept deliveries?

Tags: simcity-2013

I can import or export.  But my refineries and oil wells simply won't deliver to the trade port, only trade depots.

Comment: did you disable your specialisation buildings? What happens if you disable your trade depots, will your other buildings deliver to your ports then?

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Accept local deliveries" for the oil/plastic/fuel at the trade depots? (and making sure it is checked for the trade port)

Comment: [This might also be related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/109250/27134) - an issue caused by building orders preventing my power plant from getting coal

Answer (score 1):

Based on some of the issues seen for recycling centers that all of the buildings of a particular type are grouped together as one controller/scheduler. Therefore all of the coal mines on the map will send their loads to a single trade depot/port until its full and then move on to the next one. This makes it incredibly difficult to shut down older trade depots (as 'accept local deliveries' is sometimes ignored and/or what's on hand won't get exported as all of the trucks are swarming another depot. IMHO if you want the port to be used you'll have to nuke the trade depot (you won't have to keep them once the port has been unlocked).